# Avoid re-encoded videos on Facebook

Tags: facebook

I have been uploading a lot of videos to Facebook recently, but I don't know whether Facebook will re-encode a video if the video doesn't meet their requirements. Which render options are valid so that Facebook will leave my video untouched?

**Options**

- Maximum file size (MB)
- Maximum video length (Hour)
- Maximum bitrate (Mbps)
- Maximum resolution
- Maximum frame rate
- 10-bit bit depth support
- Reference frame (Does Facebook bother this?)

Answer (score 3):

The only information the provide on this is from [Facebook Help](https://www.facebook.com/help/154271141375595/):

> **How can I make sure my videos are high quality?**
>
> The easiest way to optimize the quality of your videos is to upload HD
>   video.
>
> If you're exporting your video from editing software (ex: Final Cut
>   Pro, Avid, iMovie) we recommend these custom settings:
>
> - H.264 video with AAC audio in MOV or MP4 format
> - An aspect ratio no larger than 1280px wide and divisible by 16px
> - A frame rate at, or below, 30fps
> - Stereo audio with a sample rate of 44,100hz
>
> Your software's guide should include information about exporting video
>   with custom settings.
>
> Keep in mind that videos must be less than 45 minutes long and smaller
>   than 1.75 GB. The longer your video is, the larger its file size will
>   be. This may affect the quality of the video.

Beyond this, it's impossible to say what they do to the videos uploaded to them. Chances are they will re-encode all videos regardless of what comes in, to ensure they are exactly what they need them to be.

Comment: Yeah, I upload a 720p HD video. But there's a big loss of quality compared to the source. Unfortunately, video editing programs doesn't have a preset option where you can maintain the higher quality of the video by spending longer time, because the video is around 3 mins, even the slowest preset option won't take longer than 30 mins.